# Slow wireless internet

Tags: internet

Just returned to linux after few years, wireless internernet connects but damn slow even though it is not the case for my mobile phone or laptop (windows seven). Can anyone guide me to get rid of this ????

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1

What worked for me was installing the Wicd Network Manager.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

You may or may not also need to uninstall the default network manager.

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

### Method 2

If /etc/nsswitch.conf has this line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

Try editing it so it instead says:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

### Method 3

Another suggestion is to type this in the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci  
sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1
```

And if the internet speed improves, then:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
```

and type into the file:

```
options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1
```

### Method 4

IPv6 can cause issues, so to prefer IPv4 instead:

```
sudo nano /etc/gai.conf
```

Locate this line (note that it says 100 at the end, not 10):

```
#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```

and remove the #.

Sources:
http://www.techdrivein.com/2012/09/slow-erratic-wifi-ubuntu1204-fixed.html
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175345
https://askubuntu.com/a/790022/628841